# Sum of power functions over a simplex

Tags: multivariable-calculus, summation

Let $d \ge 1$ be a positive integer. Let $n,m$ be another positive integers subject to $m\ge n+d$. Let $\vec{x} := (x_1,x_2,\cdots,x_d)$ be real numbers   such that all of them cannot be equal to unity at the same time.  By successively  summing over  each dimension , using the geometric sum formula and then simplifying the result I showed that:
\begin{eqnarray}
S_n^m(\vec{x}) := \sum\limits_{n \le i_1 < i_2 < \cdots < i_d \le m} \prod\limits_{l=1}^d {x_l^{i_l}} &=&
\sum\limits_{j=-1}^{d-1} (-1)^{j+1} \frac{(\prod\limits_{l=1}^{d-j-1} x_l^{n+l-1}) (\prod\limits_{l=d-j}^d x_l^{m+1})}{\prod\limits_{l=0}^j(1- \prod\limits_{\eta=0}^l x_{d-j+\eta}) \cdot \prod\limits_{l=0}^{d-j-2}(1- \prod\limits_{\eta=0}^l x_{d-j-1-\eta})}\\
&=& \left(\prod\limits_{l=1}^d x_l^{n-1}\right)\frac{\det(-\prod\limits_{l=i}^d x_l + \prod\limits_{l=i}^d x_l^{j+1+(m-n+1-d)\delta_{j,d}})_{i,j=1}^d}{\det(-1+\prod\limits_{l=i}^d x_l^j)_{i,j=1}^d}
\end{eqnarray}
Now, the sum in question is defined for every $\vec{x} \in {\mathbb R}^d$ including $\vec{x} = (1,1,\cdots,1)$. However the right hand side is not determined at $\vec{x} = (1,1,\cdots,1)$ . The question is how do I compute all partial derivatives of the sum at $(1,1,\cdots,1)$. In other words I need :
\begin{eqnarray}
\left. \left(\prod\limits_{l=1}^d \frac{1}{b_l!}\frac{d^{b_l}}{d x_l^{b_l}}  x_l^{a_l} \right) S^m_n(\vec{x}) \right|_{\vec{x} = (1,1,\cdots,1)} = ?
\end{eqnarray}
for $(b_1,\cdots,b_d) \in {\mathbb N}^d_+$ and some $(a_1,\cdots,a_d) \in {\mathbb R}^d$.

Answer (score 1):

Let us answer this question for $d=2$. We have:
\begin{eqnarray}
&&x_1 x_2 (x_1+x_2-x_1 x_2) S^m_n(1-x_1,1-x_2) = \\
&&x_1(1-x_1)^{a_1+n} (1-x_2)^{a_2+n+1} - (x_1+x_2-x_1 x_2)(1-x_1)^{a_1+n} (1-x_2)^{a_2+m+1} + x_2(1-x_1)^{a_1+m+1} (1-x_2)^{a_2+m+1}
\end{eqnarray}
We see that the sum $S^m_n$ is a rational function of two variables $x_1$ and $x_2$. Clearly the numerator is of the form:
\begin{equation}
Numerator = x_1 x_2 \sum\limits_{(l_1,l_2) \in {\mathbb N}_+^2} {\mathcal A}_{l_1,l_2} x_1^{l_1} x_2^{l_2}
\end{equation}
where 
\begin{equation}
{\mathcal A}_{l_1,l_2} = (-1)^{l_1+l_2} \left[
\binom{a_1+n}{l_1} \binom{a_2+m+1}{l_2}
+\binom{a_1+n}{l_1} (\binom{a_2+m+1}{l_2+1} - \binom{a_2+n+1}{l_2+1}) 
-\binom{a_2+m+1}{l_2} (\binom{a_1+m+1}{l_1+1} - \binom{a_1+n}{l_1+1}) 
\right]
\tag{I}
\end{equation}
The denominator is of the form:
\begin{equation}
Denominator = x_1 x_2 \sum\limits_{(l_1,l_2) \in \{0,1\}^2 , l_1+l_2 \ge 1} (-1)^{l_1+l_2+1} x_1^{l_1} x_2^{l_2}
\end{equation}
Dividing the numerator by the denominator we get  another polynomial in two variables $\sum\limits_{l_1,l_2}{\mathcal B}_{l_1,l_2} x_1^{l_1} x_2^{l_2}$.  The coefficients of the later poly6nomial satisfy following recursion relations:
\begin{equation}
{\mathcal A}_{l_1,l_2} = {\mathcal B}_{l_1,l_2-1} 1_{l_2\ge 1} + {\mathcal B}_{l_1-1,l_2}1_{l_1\ge 1} - {\mathcal B}_{l_1-1,l_2-1}1_{l_1\ge 1} 1_{l_2 \ge 1}
\end{equation}
The solution to this recursion relation reads:
\begin{equation}
{\mathcal B}_{l_1,l_2} = \sum\limits_{j=0}^{l_2} \sum\limits_{j_1=j}^{l_2} (-1)^j \binom{j_1}{j} {\mathcal A}_{l_1+1+j,l_2-j_1}
\tag{II}
\end{equation}
Now, the sum in question reads:
\begin{equation}
 {\mathcal B}_{b_1,b_2} (-1)^{b_1+b_2}
\end{equation}
Now instering (I) into (II) and simplifying the result we get:
\begin{eqnarray}
&&\sum\limits_{n \le i_1 < i_2 \le m} \binom{i_1+a_1}{b_1} \binom{i_2+a_2}{b_2} = \\
&&
\sum\limits_{j=0}^{b_2} (-1)^{j+1} \left. \left[\binom{a_1+n}{1+b_1+j} \binom{a_2+\xi-j}{1+b_2-j} - \binom{1+a_1+\xi}{2+b_1+j} \binom{a_2+m-j}{b_2-j}\right] \right|_{\xi=n}^{\xi=m}
\end{eqnarray}