# Bizarre differential identity.

Tags: calculus, summation

Let $d\ge 1$ be an integer. Let $m$ and $n$ be integers subject to $m \ge n+d-1$. The question is to prove the following identity.
\begin{equation}
\sum\limits_{j=-1}^{d-1} \sum\limits_{\underset{d_1,d_2,d_3\ge 0}{d_1+d_2+d_3=d}} \frac{(-1)^{j+1}}{d_1! d_2! d_3!}\left(d n + (j+1) (m+1-n) + \binom{d-j-1}{2}\right)_{(d_1)} (-1)^{d_1} {\mathcal A}_{d_2,j} {\mathcal A}_{d_3,j}
= \binom{m-n+1}{d}
\end{equation} 
where 
\begin{equation}
{\mathcal A}_{n,j} := \left. \frac{d^n}{d z^n}\left( \prod\limits_{l=0}^j \frac{z}{1 - (1-z)^{l+1}}\right) \right|_{z=0}
\end{equation}
This identity follows from taking the limit $\vec{x} \rightarrow (1,1,\cdots,1)$ in $S^m_n(\vec{x})$ in [Sum of power functions over a simplex](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1198551/sum-of-power-functions-over-a-simplex) . Is there a way of proving this identity using a different method than that used in deriving the later question ?

Comment: The answer to this question-- in a slightly different notation-- is given in here.  http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1620040/is-there-a-closed-form-expression-for-the-following-sum/1677425#1677425